# Free jqGrid TreeGrid - Unload Data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

As part of the next Project, I'm looking for a solution that will let me support an on-demand load of the tree hierarchy.

I know jqGrid support that.

My problem is this:  Since I need to support also a size of 3-10 millions of hierarchy branches, I wonder if there is a way to unload branches that are not in use anymore.  For example, if I open root-a-b-c, and I now go and open root-a-d-f, I would want to be able to release branches b-c from memory.

Can this be done in jqGrid?

Thanks,

Tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `afterCollapseNode` callback, which will be called after the node will be collapsed. Inside of the callback you can use `getNodeDepth` method to get all children node (leafs and sub-nodes recursively) and then remove the elements from the grid. Finally one should set `loaded` property of the collapsed node to `false`. I think the result will be what you want to implement. I'll consider to implement such behavior in TreeGrid in the future (by introducing a new option).